# LVM: Creation difference between CentOS 7 and CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos7, filesystems, centos6, lvm

I have CentOS 6 & 7 server and am creating 512 MB logical volumes:

CentOS 7:

```
sudo lvcreate -v -n lvname -L 512M rootvg && sudo mkfs.xfs -L "lvname" /dev/mapper/rootvg-lvnamee
```

CentOS 6:

```
sudo lvcreate -v -n lvname -L 512M rootvg && sudo mkfs.ext4 -L "lvname" /dev/mapper/rootvg-lvname
```

Now the commands work fine, but when I issue `df -h /fs-name`, on CentOS 7, I get Size=509M and on CentOS 6, I get Size=488M.  Why does CentOS 6 take up so much space and how can I get it closer to CentOS 7's size of 509M?

Comment: How do you measure? Could you please share the details, the output of the commands?

Comment: Aside - CentOS 6 is now well out of support and really must not be used for anything.  CentOS7 is technically still supported for another ~10 months but its pretty mouldy already.  Consider your exit strategy and where you want to land.

Comment: Why do you claim or assume that the Issue is due to "CentOS 7 vs CentOS 6" when you are obviously using 2 Different Commands ? If you had used the Exact Same Command on 2 machines & got Differing Sizes , then the Question would be valid. Ideally the Question should be "Why ext4 vs xfs have Differing Sizes ...." !

Comment: Maybe show a `vgdisplay -v` and `lvdisplay` for the LVs, too. What about block sizes of underlying devices?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference is mainly because you use two different filesystems:

> CentOS 7: sudo lvcreate -v -n lvname -L 512M rootvg && sudo mkfs.**xfs**
> -L "lvname" /dev/mapper/rootvg-lvnamee
> CentOS 6: sudo lvcreate -v -n lvname -L 512M rootvg && sudo mkfs.**ext4** -L "lvname"
> /dev/mapper/rootvg-lvname

If you want to reduce the reserved for `root` space (by default 5%) use command:

```
mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -L "lvname" /dev/mapper/rootvg-lvname
```

(0 mean no reserved space)

Comment: I understand but I would like to know why such difference in space consumed and if there is anything on CentOS 6 that I can do differently to reclaim space consumed.

Comment: @JKC, create on 7 to be ext4 and you will have the same size. (or on 6 to be xfs)

Answer (score 5):

The file systems used in those commands are different, one is [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) the other one is [XFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS).

See also [How to Choose Your Red Hat Enterprise Linux File System](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3129891)

The ext4 file system is [reserving](https://man.archlinux.org/man/mke2fs.8#m) 5% of disk that can be used only by root user.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way we can change it so that it does not reserve that 5% or make it less?

Comment: You can use `tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdaX` https://man.archlinux.org/man/tune2fs.8.en#m

Comment: The filesystem must be unmounted.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer from here https://chiaforum.com/t/ext4-users-remember-to-reduce-reserved-blocks/1972

By default ext4 reserves 5% of your disk for the root user. That made sense in 1999, but that’s insane now. You can run this command (as root) to reduce reserved blocks to around 4GB. On a 16TB ext4 file-system that will free up 795GB (since the default of 5% reserved = 800GB reserved for root!).

tune2fs -r 1000000 /dev/

This instantly frees up the space. You don’t need to unmount or remount or restart or anything.

But first use “lsblk” and “df” commands to identify the ext4 file-systems to tune.

And be careful! Running any command directly against any /dev/ file as root is always dangerous. Practice on a computer/drive that’s not important first.

Comment: When creating `ext4` you can always use option `-m` to define the percentage of reserved space (can be 0 of course).